# Cómo personalizar mi tema de "Oh my posh"?

Tags: json

Estoy tratando de personalizar un tema de Oh my posh, pero no logro hacer que aparezca la versión de "npm" luego del logo, es decir, quisiera que apareciera algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que aparece es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, solo me aparece el logo de "npm" sin la versión. El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
{
      "background": "#29315A",
      "foreground": "#5fb157",
      "leading_diamond": " \ue0b6",
      "properties": {
        "display_mode": "files",
        "fetch_package_manager": true,
        "fetch_version": true,
        "npm_icon": "<#FE4A49>\ue71e </>",
        "yarn_icon": "<#44FFD2>\uf487 Yarn</>"
      },
      "style": "diamond",
      "template": "{{ if .PackageManagerIcon }}{{ .PackageManagerIcon }} {{ end }}\ue718 {{ .Full }}",
      "trailing_diamond": "\ue0b4",
      "type": "node"
},
```

Favor alguien que sepa de esto y me ayude.